# chrubuntu questions - on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

This question relates to this Q on the main site:

- [Chrubuntu terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327238/chrubuntu-terminal-issue)

Having done the traditional "google search" (other providers may be used) I came across this blog post that describes chrubuntu and how to install it.

- http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html

At first glance it looks like a set of instructions and an install script to install whatever variant of 'buntu on a chrome-book.

Looking at this quote:

> I've rewritten the ChrUbuntu script to pull packages directly from
>   official ubuntu.com sources rather than utilizing my own
>   pre-configured, static image of an Ubuntu installation

Obviously in my mind, chrubuntu questions would have been off-topic since no-one really would have known what that image the author was using.

Looking more in detail now with the [new script](https://googledrive.com/host/0B0YvUuHHn3MndlNDbXhPRlB2eFE/chrubuntu-install.txt) it does do a few things (autologin, adds official chrome repo) but all in all, it looks fairly vanilla using official sources.

Thus, to my question: are Chrubuntu questions on-topic on AU or off-topic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Despite the questions title of "ChrUbuntu", it's simply Ubuntu installed on Chrome. So long as the distribution is actually upstream I think it's okay. The install method isn't covered exactly under the "official distribution"

Answer (score -3):

I say if it changes the default behaviour of Ubuntu and our users may not be used to install/use it, is off-topic. Unix & Linux has already questions about [Chrubuntu and they are getting answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ChrUbuntu%20is:q).

I don't see how something that may or may not change how ubuntu default installation will be on topic here.