# How to resolve conflicting information about "Chrubuntu" policy/status?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope, derivatives

My understanding is that we do not currently consider Chrubuntu to be an unofficial derivative (or even a separate derivative at all), and that the current consensus is *not* to close questions as off-topic for being about a problem on a Chrubuntu system. At least provided that the problem isn't about issues arising from an unofficially supported *Ubuntu installation method.*

- [chrubuntu questions - on-topic or off-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7095/chrubuntu-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic)
  See the [overwhelmingly more upvoted answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7098/22949) there, seeming to reflect community consensus.

However, I've noticed this recently closed question--which is *not* about any method of installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook, official or otherwise--where the comments appear to indicate it was closed because the close-voters considered Chrubuntu to be a separate, unofficial distribution:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/396785/cant-run-minecraft

Something ought to be fixed in this situation, but I'm not sure what.

1. If Chrubuntu is not a separate and unofficial derivative and that's really why [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396785/cant-run-minecraft) is closed, it should be reopened. And its comments should be cleaned up.
2. If I'm missing something and Chrubuntu is (or sometimes is??) a separate and unofficial derivative, then we should have an updated answer on [that meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7095/chrubuntu-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic). If we're keeping some new Chrubuntu questions open and closing others (and considering that to be appropriate), that should also be explained. And *possibly* some comments should be cleaned up.
3. If that question really should remain closed, but for reasons unrelated to it being about a "Chrubuntu" system, then that should be explained, *especially to the OP.* And comments should definitely be cleaned up. (I haven't seen another reason to think it should be closed, though.)

I suspect that inadequate communication about the status of "Chrubuntu" may have caused a problem in numerous questions, which might need addressing. But I also suspect I may not know the whole story, having returned from being (mostly) inactive on the site for an extended time. So I'm focusing on this one specific Chrubuntu-related question, rather than trying to figure out anything about all of them.

What should be done with that particular Minecraft question? What is the status of "Chrubuntu"? Please advise.

Comment: I must admit, I had forgotten about that meta post, I still believe however, that this question should be closed, whether it's OT, bug or dupe. btw, nice to see you back, it's been a while :)

Comment: Agree with Seth: definitely nice to see you back! Hope you are doing OK.

Comment: Another question/example http://askubuntu.com/q/403590/169736. The drive should build OK in Ubuntu, but user can't since he's using Chrubuntu and some weirdness happen with apt that don't allow him to download the correct sources for his kernel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Chrubuntu is stock Ubuntu with a different install vector. Everything but installing it is on topic.

That's the current policy boiled to the bone... But on closer inspection (and with help from [the related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396785/cant-run-minecraft)) you can see that it's not a stock kernel that's being used. For Arm Chromebooks, it has been necessary to use custom kernels to support the architecture. *However* they do use stock kernels in x86 Chromebooks.

I think I'm *personally* more for supporting it while it's still just a kernel. I've asked half my questions while under the influence of a dodgy third party kernel (and have asked questions about them) so I'd be a hypocrite to suggest that non-stock kernels alone are enough to make something off-topic.

But I do recognise the problem here. If we support this, why don't we support that? Or this over here? That is a valid concern.

The mods have discussed this before (that's where that meta post came from) so I'll bring it up again in our next meeting. Until then, let's just stick with the existing guidance and leave them open unless they're about installing.

Comment: Did something came up?

Answer (score 6):

I will give a reason why I voted to close first:

In that particular question, to me, doesn't seems to be a problem within the bounds that *Ubuntu will have the same behavior* and more like *the changes made to Ubuntu for Chrubuntu are causing problems*. Correct me if I'm wrong, but:

1. Minecraft requires kernel >3.6 and through it is Saucy (kernel 3.10) it has 3.4. (*change made by Chrubuntu*).
2. The error is about a bug already fixed upstream in [newer versions of the kernel.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1220807/comments/9) Is reproducible as long as you use old Ubuntu kernels. I suggested to install `linux-generic` in comment and if Chrubuntu hasn't modified anything else it should work. If it doesn't then it's Chrubuntu to blame, *not Ubuntu*.
3. The buggy behavior appears and [has solution is Precise](https://askubuntu.com/a/300315/169736). OP is using Saucy and should benefit of the fix. If Chrubuntu is modifying Ubuntu in such way that things that *things that shouldn't happen in Ubuntu happens to Chrubuntu users* that weighs even more my VtC as "Not about Ubuntu".

So, to solve OP problem he should drop that and use Ubuntu instead. That seems reasonable enough to make that question off-topic due **This is not about Ubuntu**, instead of **bug** (which is the correct close reason if he were using Quantal).

This is the general response to all Chrubuntu questions:

If the questions/problems asked by users of Chrubuntu wouldn't be asked if they were using *stock* Ubuntu, we should treat Chrubuntu as derivative and make it off-topic.

Comment: I agree with this answer. We could also have closed the question as a dupe though.

Comment: @Seth of what??

Comment: Of Luis's how to install and troubleshoot minecraft client.

Comment: @Seth that will not help since is that the kernel used by Chrubuntu is not supported ;).

Comment: Oh, that's true.

Comment: "Should drop that and use Ubuntu instead": pretty much impossible on early chromebooks/chromeboxes, Chrubuntu and Crouton are the closest one can get.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin then they should drop chromebooks/chromeboxes and get *real* systems ;)