# Can we please decide if Chrubuntu installation and usage is on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We've got couple of questions about ChrUbuntu, installing Ubuntu on a Chrome Book, problems that happens *only* when you use these modified scripts. So, they are welcomed with all that it carries or they should find home in UL?

Comment: Also previously discussed here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8025/how-to-resolve-conflicting-information-about-chrubuntu-policy-status

Comment: @fossfreedom that conversation was inconclusive, hence, new discussions are warranted.

Comment: "Inconclusive"? How is that inconclusive? Look at the votes on the answers... That's not inconclusive, thats about as cut and dry as you can get.

Comment: @jrg "The mods have discussed this before (that's where that meta post came from) so *I'll bring it up again in our next meeting.* Until then, let's just stick with the existing guidance and leave them open unless they're about installing."